# Firebase Realtime Database listen to data added n hours from now?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to somehow do it with `startAt()`  and `endAt()`?

```
db.ref('/items')
  .orderByChild('createdAt')
  .endAt(new Date().getTime() + 180 * 60 * 1000) // Updated
  .on('value', () => {/* ... */})
```

### Edit:

What I'm trying to achieve is getting all the `items` that are currently in the database and listening for the newly added `items` from the last `n hours`.

Using a static number like `endAt(1669743560642)`, lets say user is there for a few minutes, the number `1669743560642` will not be updated to the new time that has gone by, it's important to somehow that value gets somehow updated in real time.

So from (user's/server time) up to `n hours`.

Exports from Realtime Database:

```json
{
  "items": {
    "-NI3TAUjGNRlAUQ3Yc8K": {
      "createdBy": "5gQ5cfGN15WCSa9RZVvAYXhKTyc2",
      "createdAt": 1669743560642
    },
    "-NI3i-jMEyx_inQCaALr": {
      "createdBy": "lc4BcHOls7cBuTVmbNo9LmtDdlf2",
      "createdAt": 1669747710748
    },
    "-NI8-Jb_Qvd8gA3nG9cv": {
      "createdBy": "5gQ5cfGN15WCSa9RZVvAYXhKTyc2",
      "createdAt": 1669819620439
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So why don't you `startAt(1673880962233)`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well startAt should point to the time now, if I would use `1673880962233` I would not get the newly added items.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Isn't there some special parameter that I could pass? Or a different way without using `startAt()` and `endAt()`?

Comment: You need to pass a value of `createdAt` to `startAt` and `endAt`, and `1673880962233` seems like a good starting point. Did you try the code that I suggested? What is the output that you get with that? What happens if you then also remove `endAt(10)`? If you still get no output, please edit your question to also show the data in `items` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get nodes with a `createdAt` value of N hours ago or newer. For that I see two problems in your code:

1. Since Firebase Realtime Database always orders the value in ascending order, that's a `startAt` operation, not an `endAt` operation.
2. Since you want N hours in the past, you need to **subtract** from the current timestamp, not add to it.

So something like this:

```
db.ref('/items')
  .orderByChild('createdAt')
  .startAt(Date.now() - 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 8 hours ago
  .on('value', () => {/* ... */})
```

---

There is no way to make that `startAt` value dynamic though. Once you create a query, it is immutable. So if you want the window of data to move, you'll have create another query for that.

In most cases where I need this, I actually end up post-filtering the nodes in my application code. So I create the query with the `startAt` value as above, and then add additional logic to expire items locally too. When you have a `limit` on the query too, that won't work or be harder, so I try to avoid needing that combination.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution that I went with, I don't believe a few minutes would matter that much, reloading the screen we could just re-run the query, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I now finally get what you actually asked. I added a small extra section to my doc on queries being idempotent and a potential approach.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good idea. If it gets to a point where user's spend a lot of time in that screen, we could just end up filtering them locally.